# Server Architecture Setup, what type of services should I use?

Tags: user-interface, server, architecture

Let's start with some backstory, I'm not an experience coder at all. I know some HTML & CSS and some simple python, some fundamentals you know. I have decided to start a project to get more familiar with Web Server building. So let me tell what I need help with, I don't know what types of systems I should use, and what system does what thing. So I need kinda of a push in the right direction I should go.

This is how I want my server setup.

Front-End and Back-End needs to separate.

Front-End is supposed to be my personal website that everyone can see but with an login function to control some back-end, like hangfire processing service, or If I just wanna setup some front end stuff that requires to be logged in to see.

I want all my stuff separate through containers which I guess Docker compose will do.

Back-End I want to be able to upload web applications that either I can run through my login function or if I wanna publish my work to anyone through my front-end.

Thats kinda it. I know its alot, but I also wanna say that all I really need help with is like a simple simple list of services to use, like this for example. (Examples are like NGINX, Docker, NodeJs, Kubernetes etc, etc)

Frontend = ?

Login & Auth server= ? (Auth I guess Jws auth server?)

Container = ?

Backend = ?

Frontend & Backend Communicator = ?

MySQL database for login = ?

I would assume that alot of microservices will be involved.

If you have any question feel to ask me. I tried my best explaining my situation, i've tried googling alot. I also know that there is alot alot of work ahead of me, this is project that I will try to finish within 1-3 years honestly, since there is most likely going to involve learning a couple of programming language.

I havent really tried anything since I'm really stuck.

Answer (score 0):

This is what we do in our projects:

we containerize our modules (api, db, ui) and use nginx as gateway between front-end and back-end. nginx rewrite requests based on addresses and point user request to docker-containers which will handle it. this way our structure is not visible to normal users. nginx has also another duty, it will serve front-end files.

Comment: Damn thank you so much man. This is what I hjave been looking for so all I really need to learn in NGINX and docker?

Comment: exactly, and all containers you need is already on docker hub. just pull mysql, nginx and jdk8 (jdk for java projects if you use something else to run your project pull its docker container)